# Use of a friend class to hide private static callback methods

Tags: c++, callback, private, friend

I need to register a table of function pointers with some API. Let's say the API looks like this:

```
void (*FuncPtr)(void*);
void RegisterCallbacks(FuncPtr const (&callbacks)[10], void* context);
```

Since I'm writing OOP code, I create static "thunk" methods in my class that in turn call methods on an object of my class. I use the `context` pointer to pass the pointer to my object. I want to statically allocate the entire table of callback pointers at static initialization time. So I end up with this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    static void Thunk (void* context)
    {
        reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(context)->Method();
    }

    void Method ();

    //
    // More callback thunks and methods...
    //

    MyClass ()
    {
        RegisterCallbacks(s_callbackTable, this);
    }

private:

    static const FuncPtr s_callbackTable[];
}

//
// In the .cpp file:
//
const FuncPtr MyClass::s_callbackTable[] =
{
    &MyClass::Thunk,
    ...
};
```

<s>The problem with this approach is that I need to make `MyClass::Thunk` publically visible so that the static initialization can access it.</s>

**Edit: I was mistaken. Apparently you don't need to make it public to do that.**

I'd rather not though. I can think of two ways to solve this.

**Which approach is better?**

1. Create a private static method, and make the callback table a static variable inside the method. This way I can initialize it using pointers to private methods as well. Call the private static method from inside the constructor to get the table.
2. Create a separate class that contains public static thunk methods and make that class a friend of `MyClass`. Forward declare that class in the header for `MyClass`, just to allow the friend declaration. I like this because it also hides the thunk methods completely from any external consumers. Not really sure if there is a tangible benefit to that though.

   Like so:

   ```
   // .h file:

   class MyClassInternals

   class MyClass
   {
   public:

       void Method ();

   private:

       friend class MyClassInternals;

       static const FuncPtr s_callbackTable[];
   }

   // .cpp file:

   class MyClassInternals
   {
   public:

       static void Thunk(void* context)
       {
           reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(context)->Method();
       }
   }

   const FuncPtr MyClass::s_callbackTable[] =
   {
       &MyClassInternals::Thunk,
       ...
   };
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply keep *all of the trampoline machinery* inside the constructor implementation (.cpp), no need to expose **anything** about the trampolines at the interface level (.h):

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
    struct trampolines {
        static void method1(void *ctx) { ((MyClass *)ctx)->method1(); }
        static void method2(void *ctx) { ((MyClass *)ctx)->method2(); }
    };
    static void (*callbacks[])(void*) = { trampolines::method1,
                                          trampolines::method2 };
    register_callbacks(callbacks, this);
}
```

You don't even need to include in the (.h) the header of the C library that uses the callback/context interface. This is cleaner as the clients of your module won't depend on those C details.

Comment: The methods don't even need to be public. The `trampolines` struct, by virtue of being defined within the scope of `MyClass` inherits the same semantics as an inner class, i.e., it can access private methods of the containing class. See http://ideone.com/Ai7WW7. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5714720/179895 that makes the same suggestion as you do.

Comment: @TripShock: Thanks for the clarification. I'm not a big supporter of `private`/`protected` and didn't know about this subtlety of local classes inside constructor/method scope. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make `Thunk` visible to use it when initialising a member of the same class.

After fixing a few minor syntax errors your original example compiles just fine when `Thunk` is `private`.

See https://ideone.com/VmSasp

Comment: That's weird...what the hell was I doing :P

Comment: Is there any value in being able to hide the private thunk methods completely from the interface of `MyClass`?