# What is the correct way to encapsulate helper functions in C++?

Tags: c++

Given a class:

```
class myClass{
// ...

private:
   int helperFuncForA();
   int secondhelperFuncForA();
public:
   void A();

// ...
};
```

Suppose that the helper functions are not used outside of `A`; how do I encapsulate them such that calling them outside of `A` is impossible? Do I do:

```
class myClass{
// ...

public:
   class {
   private:
      int helperFuncForA();
      int secondhelperFuncForA();
   public:
      void call();
   } A;

// ...
};
```

and then call by writing:

```
myClass obj;
obj.A.call();
```

? Perhaps, I could overload `A`'s `()` operator instead of making the `call()` function for convenience. What is the correct way?

Comment: Your first example already accomplishes your goal, the private functions by definition make it impossible to call them outside of A. You do not need the internal class

Comment: A `private` member function cannot be called outside the class nor in a derived class. If you worry about that the `private` member function can be called outside another specific member function then move that code into a lambda or free function which is only available in the C++ (implementation) code (but not in the header). However, if you are the author of the class then a simple doc. note (i.e. a comment) might be sufficient as well.

Comment: Unless the helper functions needs access to the `myClass` object, put the function in an anonymous namespace in the translation unit where `A` is defined?

Comment: If you have the need to call `obj.A.call();` outside a member function of A, you have obscure design in my eyes! If a helper function is needed to manipulate an object outside a member function, you should rethink your design!

Comment: And if you *really* need `class A`, you can change the name `call` to `operator()`, so it remains `obj.A();`

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is using of lambdas:

```
class myClass{
// ...

private:
   // remove from here 
   //int helperFuncForA();
   //int secondhelperFuncForA();
public:
   void A();

// ...
};

// somewhere
void myClass::A()
{
   auto helperFuncForA = [this]() -> int
   {
      //...
      return 1;
   };

   auto secondhelperFuncForA = [this]() -> int
   {
      //...
      return 2;
   };

   //...
   int x = helperFuncForA(); 

   x += secondhelperFuncForA();
}
```

Comment: Is this common practice? How would this be accomplished pre c++11?

Comment: @flappybird7 Using lambda is common practice.
Doing the same thing before C++11 is rather difficult and would look like overengineering.
Theoretically, AFAIR, according to the C++03 standard, a class can be declared inside a function, and the `helperFuncForA(), secondhelperFuncForA()` functions can be implemented inside this local class, but not all compilers supported this feature.
Look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714616/usage-of-local-class-in-c-function)

Answer (score 1):

If some method can only be used by in the function void A(), you probably need a class.

But you can do something like this if you want :

```
#include <iostream>

class ClassTest
{
    public:
        struct A{
            
            private:
               void helperFunc() {
                std::cout << "Executing Helper Func " << std::endl;
                }
            public:   
            void operator() (){
                helperFunc();
            }
        };
    A a;
    
    void classFunc(){
        //a.helperFunc(); <- Impossible helperFunc private
        a(); 
    }
};

int main()
{
    ClassTest c;
    c.classFunc();// Print : Executing Helper Func 
    //OR
    c.a();// Print e: Executing Helper Func 
}
```