# Does the following code structure or design implementation have an Idiomatic Name?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, instantiation, idioms

Within the C++ language, many will come across various design patterns that have a designated name in which we would call an Idiom, such as `SFINAE`, `RAII`, `CRTP`, `Polymorphism`, etc...

Consider this following code snippet in its most basic form...

```
template<typename T>
auto make_object = [](T val) {
    class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(T val) : value_{val} {}
        T value() const { return value_; }
    private:            
        T value_;
    };
    Foo foo(val);
    return foo;
};

// in some other code block, scope, or translation
int main() {
    auto bar = make_object<float>( 3.1f );
    auto val = bar.value();
    return 0;
}
```

Here I'm using a templated lambda to generate or create an instance of a class `Foo` that is fully contained(declared and defined) within the scope of the Lamba body's implementation and through the use of auto type deduction variable `bar` is of type `Foo` where you can treat it and access it as if you had declared `Foo` as its own separate class... Does this type of design pattern have a specific idiomatic name that I'm not aware of?

Comment: `Foo` itself is called a *local class*. I doubt there is a specific name for this specific usage. Also, making `make_object` a lambda seems pointless to me. A function template like `template<typname T> auto make_object(T) {...}` will work fine.

Comment: The idiomatic name for this is "Design Flaw"

Comment: You could take a look at [Usage of local class in C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714616) there is also an answer pointing to a cppcon talk that makes usage of it and explains why it can be useful.

Comment: t.niese I've seen this video before, it just never dawned on me that the section for explaining the benefits of RAII was relevant or related to my question. However, the pattern I've shown above may not be RAII directly but could be used to implement some form of it. I have also read the documents that were provided by a different answer on the same page in regards to Trampoline functions, Continuation-Passing, and Tail Recursion, however, they fit the model for other languages more directly such as Scheme, Lisp & Haskel. This also led me to the papers on the `Thunk` process...

Comment: @ArminMontigny Not necessarily, it would depend on how you design it, plan to use it, and how you actually use it. After following the link provided by user t.niese, it led me to a video that I've already seen by Jason Turner. He doesn't use a `lambda` to do this directly, but similarly, he uses some form of `RAII` within his presentation that is closely related to my code structure & implementation. This could also be used to design `Thunk` type methods, `Continuation-Passing (CPS)`, and `Trampoline` type functions or callbacks. One would need to be careful in their design implementations.

Comment: @FrancisCugler the problem with certain design patterns is that it is hard to come up with a good explanation/example of why they are useful. In simplified examples that fit the scope of StackOverflow (for both question and answers) you often have the problem that the example you came up with can be solved in various ways and with other design patterns that (for these simplified examples) seemingly fit better, and don't really illustrate the necessity/benefit of that pattern over another pattern. Especially if you currently don't need to use such a pattern yourself.

Comment: @t.niese I understand what you are stating, however, with this question... It would be nice to know if such a name or label exists... that way if either A) future use of such code structure, or B) come across it within someone else's codebase, I can then easily identify it with clarity!

Comment: Not every pattern has a name - which does not mean that it is the case for this one - but are _"sub-"_ pattern being used in the field of an _"umbrella"_ pattern. The code you show (at least in my opinion) is for itself just something that looks like it can be a pattern and can be used (like shown in the linked answer, or video) for RAII but by itself misses crucial parts that would make it possible to identify the actual pattern. Having only passing `T val` from outside and only using it as a copy makes it difficult to pair it with a specific design pattern.

Comment: So in the current form, I would - like the first comment - just go with _local class_.

Comment: @t.niese That seems to make sense because you can use them in various ways... `RAII`, `SFINAE`, `CRTP`, and more... however, they are within the scope of a lambda as opposed to a function... it could be considered or treated as a "nested" `class` or `struct` in my use case according to the underlying implementations of lambdas...

Comment: Lambdas could be useful for currying. So I could imagine this pattern to be seen with currying and RAII. But can‘t imagine a useful use-case right now. But the shown code fragment does not indicate currying nor that the use of a lambda is required at all.